# How can I force not to show prefix for Symfony nelmio-api-doc bundle

Tags: symfony, swagger, nelmioapidocbundle

I need to hide an /rpc prefix on swagger table for some methods which are going to be used for json-rpc requests:

[image]

Which is placed from a config file nelmio_api_doc.yaml

[image]

Any suggestions are welcome! Maybe anyone knows an option like `hide_prefix: true` or something like that...